# Object getting rotated with the Array + Curve modifier

Tags: modifiers, objects, bezier-curves

I'm trying to make an object follow a simple curve, however I'm having issues with the object rotating once the curve modifier is applied on it, and I can't figure out how to have it rotate the way I want it to go.

I have the following curve, and a simple rectangle object that I want to duplicate along the path of the curve. Think of road markings following a road.

[image]

[image]

I've set the origin of the curve and rectangle to their respective geometries. I then set the 3D cursor at the curve's origin, and then Shift + S > Selection to Cursor on the rectangle. I've also applied all transformations as well.

When I apply the Curve modifier to the rectangle, it rotates the rectangle, and no matter what I do it won't rotate in the way I want it to. I've tried:

- Applying different rotations on different axis
- Applying the scaling on different axis
- Rotating the curve in a bunch of ways

But it all results in the *exact same* situation where the object isn't oriented the proper direction I'd like it to be.

[image]

If it makes a difference, the curve was made via Duplicating another Object's Loop Cut and converting it into a curve, then removing the 'bottom' vertices from that curve.

How can I get the rectangle oriented correctly along the curve?

EDIT: Here's the blendfile https://pasteall.org/blend/8f47a59305a24b01aaeaa348d8611e57

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots Just edited my OP with the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've applied the curve scale, it has increased its vertices radius, bring it back to 1:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! After resetting the radius back to 1, I could rotate the rectangle without it deforming completely

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check this, if this can help. https://pasteall.org/blend/480c8368348c44a48301f5d4bcd594a8
cheers